# Required field validation with label name in MVC asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there anyway to show label as required when validating a form?
I'm asking this because I have this translated labels in my form and it would be easier if I can show those labels when user missed one instead of standard "Required" text(which is not translated).

I want to replace `[Required(ErrorMessage = "*Requird*")]` whit the translated value of `labelText: questions.number`

Here is my code: 
 
formIndex.chtml

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.number, labelText: questions.number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.number, new { @class = "form-control", @PlaceHolder = "9010" , @type="number" , @Value = "" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>
```

Answers.cs

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*Requird*")]
public int number { get; set; }
```

Comment: What do you mean by translated?

Comment: Where and how is `questions.number` defined? I don't quite understand your problem. In your  `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) ` the second argument is an empty string. You need to be more specific with your problem.

Comment: By translated I mean that those labels are loaded from the database based on chosen language, for example: if user is Dutch than labels all are in Dutch, if user is English than all the labels will be in English. @BoškoBezik that second argument needs to be empty if you want custom text otherwise you always see the text that are between those quotes.